# Ionic 2 using a function from another class

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i am trying to use the function takePicture() from camera.ts in my home.ts , however i am not sure how to do it , i have met this error Error in ./TabsPage class TabsPage - caused by: No provider for CameraPage!. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i just started learning this language a few days back

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { CameraPage } from '../../pages/camera/camera';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams: NavParams,      private camera: CameraPage) {

}

 goCam(){

this.camera.takePicture();


}

}
```

camera.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Camera} from 'ionic-native';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({

templateUrl: 'camera.html'
})
export class CameraPage {
public base64Image: string;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {


 }

takePicture(){
 Camera.getPicture({
   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   targetWidth: 1000,
   targetHeight: 1000
 }).then((imageData) => {
   // imageData is a base64 encoded string
   this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
 }, (err) => {
   console.log(err);
  });
}

 ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.takePicture();
}

 }
```

tabs.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { CameraPage } from '../camera/camera';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  tab1Root: any = HomePage;
  tab2Root: any = CameraPage;
  tab3Root: any = ContactPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a Page to another Page like you can a provider (basically instantiating it in the constructor)

You need to build a provider/service class (i.e. `camera.service.ts`) to provide the service method `takePicture`. Then both pages can use the functionality. Pages ideally shouldn't hold any cross-page state.

The specific error you see happens because all providers need to appear in `app.module.ts` under the `providers` section. Ionic is trying to search for `CameraPage` in the providers declared in `app.module.ts` but cannot find it.

Comment: Hi sir , do you mean that i would need to move all my camera.ts code to camera.service.ts instead and then i would call the function in the camera.service.ts to both camera.ts and home.ts so both pages can use it?

Comment: All code that has to do with the camera service and not the page. (i.e. only `takePicture`. Instantiate the new `CameraService` in the constructor (like you are doing the CameraPage now) for both pages and call takePicture from there. `this.cameraService.takePicture()`

Comment: Thank you sir for the help , i really appreciated it . Your explanation is clear and concise.